# Why is the parameter I am passing to my function undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am using typeahead.js and here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        var projectNumbers;
        $.getJSON("api/Project/GetAllNumbers")
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                projectNumbers = result;
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('Error: ' + err);
            });

        var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substrRegex;
                console.log(strs); // Undefined
                console.log(projectNumbers); //Filled
                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                        matches.push({ value: str });
                    }
                });

                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        $('#jobNumber').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true,
        },
          {

              name: 'projects',
              source: substringMatcher(projectNumbers),
          });

    });
</script>
```

If you look in the substringMatcher function the parameter strs is undefined. I pass it in at the bottom in the typeahead source. projectNumbers Has the data when I pass it into the function and even when I logged it to the console it had the data. strs however is undefined.

Any Suggestions?

**UPDATE**

When I load the page I am logging the return of getJSON and it is populated (line 7). If that is populated why isn't it populating when I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: You're returning a function, not calling the function and returning the result. Of course the variable is undefined.

Comment: I think this is because your code is asynchronous. Your getJSON done() is executed after the rest of your code. So when you execute "source: substringMatcher(projectNumbers)", "projectNumbers" may not have been initialized yet. But when you call the function created by "substringMatcher(projectNumbers)", "projectNumbers" is initialized. This is why :
console.log(strs); // Undefined
console.log(projectNumbers); //Filled

Tell me if it is the right answer, I'll make an answer in this case.

Comment: @nit instead of mocking the OP, why don't you explain how to fix it?

Comment: @JuanMendes I pointed out where the issue lies, what are you on about?

Comment: @nit why would the fact that I am returning a function cause the parameter I am passing in to be undefined. I am not attempting to return the parameter, just use it?

Comment: @Cyrille How would I make sure that getJSON done() is called before I pass projectNumbers into the function?

Comment: By putting $('#jobNumber').typeahead({...}) in the getJSON done.

Comment: @Cyrille make and answer with that and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your code is asynchronous. Your `getJSON done()` is executed after the rest of your code. So when you execute

`source: substringMatcher(projectNumbers)`

`projectNumbers` may not have been initialized yet. But when you call the function created by `substringMatcher(projectNumbers)`, `projectNumbers` is initialized. This is why you get :

`console.log(strs); // Undefined
console.log(projectNumbers); //Filled`